# Delete multiple records (Laravel)

Tags: html, laravel

I want to delete multiple records at one time using checkboxes. My code is not working.

my html

```
   @foreach($userallergens as $aller)
                     <input type="hidden" name="ua_id" value="{{$aller->ua_id}}">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="allergies" name="allergen[]" value="{{$aller->ua_id}}">
                      {{ $aller->allergen_name}}</label>
                       <label>Tolerance Level:<b>{{$aller->tolerance_level}}</b></label><br>

              @endforeach
```

my controller

```
 public function destroy(Request $request){
  $id=Auth::user()->id;
  $uaid=UserAllergen::where('ua_id', $request['ua_id'])->get();
 if (is_array($id)) 
    {
        UserAllergen::destroy($uaid);
    }
    else
    {
       UserAllergen::where('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();
    }



 return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('user', 'id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ua_id should be ua_id[] so the form posts it as an array, you got it right for the allergens

There are a few mistakes first:

```
$id=Auth::user()->id;
```

and

```
if (is_array($id))
```

That's never going to work since the user id is always a non array value

Then you need to make a few changes to your code

Also change this

```
UserAllergen::where('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();
```

To this

```
UserAllergen::whereIn('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();
```

Also unless ua_id is your primary key i would avoid using destroy as it bases on the table primary key (id usually), you can instead use

```
UserAllergen::where('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();
```

However, if it's the PK of your table you can use destroy in the case of the array as well reducing your code to just

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
  $uaid = $request->get('ua_id'); // array

  UserAllergen::destroy($uaid);


 return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('user', 'id'));
}
```

or

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
  $uaid = $request->get('ua_id'); // array

  UserAllergen::whereIn('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();

 return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('user', 'id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete multiple Rows (record) in Laravel 5.8:

```
$rowIds = "1,3,5";
$Rowsdeleted = explode(",", $rowIds);
foreach($Rowsdeleted as $rowId) {
    $response = YourModelName::where('id',"=",$rowId)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use in controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request){


$uaid = $request->get('ua_id'); // array

UserAllergen::whereIn('ua_id', $uaid)->delete();

return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('user', 'id'));

}
```

> when you comes with array of that id's